# Mysql Join rows from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, select, join

I am asking here because what english words i need to search for this what i want to do.
I can solve this with multiple queries then join arrays with for and foreach loops but why to do it if there is smarter way.

My query now looks like:

```
SELECT p.* , pi.path, pv.videoid
FROM products p
JOIN productimage pi ON (p.id = pi.product)
JOIN productvideo pv ON (p.id = pv.product)
WHERE p.id=:id
```

my tables look like

product:

```
|---id---|---name----|---desc---|---price---|---active----|
|---1----|---somet---|---dsa----|---456-----|---1/0-------|
|---2----|---somet2--|---ddsasa-|---44556---|---1/0-------|
```

product video:

```
|----id----|---product----|----videoid-------|
|----4-----|---1----------|-----youtubeid----|
|----4-----|---1----------|--secondyoutubeid-|
```

and same as video for images, and i want to make same for files

result like this to make it easy

```
//result of $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$arr = array(
    0 => array(
        "id" => "1",
        "name" => "hello world",
        "category" => "3",
        "videoid" => array("oneyoutubeid", "secondid", "thirdid"), //videos that is for this product
        "path" => array("imagepathofproduct", "secondimageofproduct"),
        "active" => "1"
    ),
    1 => array(
        "id" => "2",
        "name" => "hello world product 2",
        "category" => "4",
        "videoid" => array("oneyoutubeid", "secondid", "thirdid"), //videos that is for this product
        "path" => array("imagepathofproduct", "secondimageofproduct"),
        "active" => "1"
    ),
);
to use it like this: return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); and start foreach for displaying data.
```

thankyou very much

Comment: No. A simple fetch-results-into-array cannot do what you want. You'll need more a complex fetch loop to build your structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by concat and i will explode it into array.
 but still waiting for more smart solutions.

Solution:

```
SELECT p.* , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT path ORDER BY pi.id) AS images, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT videoid ORDER BY pi.id) AS videos FROM products p JOIN productimage pi ON (p.id = pi.product) JOIN productvideo pv ON (p.id = pv.product) WHERE p.id=1
```

Home it will helpt to somebody